# How to make <enter> open new tabs for the quickfix window when it is opened with "tab copen" including the first time?

Tags: quickfix

I want to work with quickfix without ever having a split window.

So I've set:

```
set switchbuf=newtab
```

as mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852763/vim-quickfix-list-launch-files-in-new-tab

Now:

```
tab copen
```

opens the quickfix window on a new tab.

But if I hit enter on a quickfix item, instead of creating a new tab, it first opens the location on a split in the current tab.

Only after this first split do new tabs get opened.

Is it possible to get new tabs from the first `<enter>`, and never see any splits?

Tested on Vim 7.4.

Comment: The <enter> cannot hold it is too late꙰ⷭⷵ

Comment: @leftaroundabout I don't understand :-)

Comment: @leftaroundabout reminds me of that famous [so]  post about parsing HTML with regex … which itself derives from something else, not sure what.

Comment: @muru: it's originally from [a famous poem](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Second_Coming_%28Yeats%29).

Comment: surely, this is a bug?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This workaround seems to work (mind the capitalized `T` in the end):

```
autocmd FileType qf nnoremap <buffer> <Enter> <C-W><Enter><C-W>T
```

It will create a mapping that is local to the `quickfix` buffer (it also works in `location lists`, since they have the same filetype, i.e. `qf`).
This mapping will first open the item under the cursor in a new window using `<C-W><Enter>` and then move it to an new tab using `<C-W>T`.

See

```
:help :autocmd
:help quickfix
:help CTRL-W_<Enter>
:help CTRL-W_T
```

Comment: Nice! BTW, are you http://stackoverflow.com/users/813602/ingo-karkat or are there disproportionately many Vim masters named Ingo?

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩 the latter, perhaps: http://vi.stackexchange.com/users/970/ingo-karkat

Answer (score 7):

This mapping does what *I think* you want, put it in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/qf.vim`.

```
nnoremap <buffer> <CR> :tabnew\|cc <C-r>=line(".")<CR><CR>
```

Comment: How does this compare to ingo's answer: http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6999/2038 At first sight, that is more readable (I understand the `ftplugin` vs `autocmd` part :-))

Comment: You mentioned in your question that you don't want splits. Ingo's mapping opens the file in a new window and moves that window to a tab while my mapping doesn't create an intermediary window. Other than that, I'd say both get the job done. The choice is yours.

Answer (score 5):

The `quickfix`/`location list` is an interesting beast. I'd recommend reading into `:help quickfix` for some inner workings of these two features (pretty much interchangeable; list commands are prefixed with `l` and quickfix with `q`)

It sounds like the default quickfix opens won't solve your problem (opening in a new tab is not supported by default)

I'd check out [QFEnter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4778). It was built to give extra control over the `quickfix` menu and it looks like it should work out of the box for you.

> Normal mode : Open an item under cursor in a new tab.
>
> Visual mode : Open items in visual block in a sequence of new tabs.
>   Quickfix window is automatically opened in the new tab to help you
>   open other Quickfix items.

Answer (score 1):

I've added the following remapping to my function which opens the quicklist:

```
nnoremap <Enter> :tab .cc<CR>
```

This plays nicely with

```
set switchbuf+=usetab
```

so that if the buffer is already open in another tab, it will use that tab rather than a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try also `:cdo tabedit`:

- `:cdo {cmd}` -- Execute `{cmd}` for every entry in the quickfix list (like `:tabdo` or `:bufdo`
- `:tabedit {pathspec}` -- Open a new tab page for `{pathspec}`

Since `:tabedit` seems to understand the quickfix line spec, `:cdo` will open a new tab page for every item in the quickfix list. In practice, I have an extra tab page open that I have to close, but it doesn't seem to omit any of the entries.

I use this to inspect all the jump locations returned by `git grep` generated by the Tim Pope `fugitive` plugin command `Ggrep`, which loads the results into the quickfix list by using `git grep` as `grepprg`, e.g.

> Find all usages of `send_email` that are NOT in `tests` directories:
>
> ```
> :Ggrep '\bsend_email\(' -- ':!**/tests/**' | cgo tabedit
> ```

You could probably achieve the same without `fugitive` and definitely with anything that populates the quickfix list. See also `:ldo`, which iterates over items in the location list, and all the `:*do` commands for other helpful automations.

Comment: You might also be interested in the `git-jump` script in git's contrib directory; `git jump grep …` opens vim with the results loaded in the quickfix. There's also `diff`, `merge`, and `ws` modes.

Comment: Nice tip, @D.BenKnoble!